# I need to develop a pagination structure using react mobx and mui pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination, mobx

I get this data from the api:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oWpU.png)

```
"meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "links": [
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "pagination.previous",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "url": "http://yuzka.uz/api/storage/5/package-lists?page=1",
                "label": "1",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "url": "http://yuzka.uz/api/storage/5/package-lists?page=2",
                "label": "2",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "url": "http://yuzka.uz/api/storage/5/package-lists?page=3",
                "label": "3",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "url": "http://yuzka.uz/api/storage/5/package-lists?page=2",
                "label": "pagination.next",
                "active": false
            }
        ],
        "path": "http://yuzka.uz/api/storage/5/package-lists",
        "per_page": 20,
        "to": 20,
        "total": 43
    }
```

meta => link includes all tags, of course { url , label , active } are included.

I am using this mui pagination:

```
<Stack spacing={2}>
          <Pagination
            count={10}
            onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value, event)}
            defaultPage={6}
            renderItem={(item) => (
              <PaginationItem
                slots={{ previous: LeftNewIcons, next: RightNewIcons }}
                {...item}
              />
            )}
          />
        </Stack>
```

It looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsnVt.png)

My problem is I don't know how to pass the data inside meta => links to Pagination

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO, what's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to pass the data inside meta => links to Pagination